# Onclick I Should get the Image of original size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have resized the image using css, I need to get the image to original size onclick
what should I do in order to do that?

Find the CSS at http://jsfiddle.net/RDcA7/

```
<style type="text/css">
.pad {
display:inline-block;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}
.pin {
background: #FEFEFE;
opacity: 1;
display: inline;
}
.pin img {
width:auto;
image-rendering:optimizeQuality;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
max-height: 200px;
max-width: 400px;
}  
</style>
```

Comment: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."*

Comment: Sorry, but it's a bit entertaining that the two initial comments here were by "Steam Engine" and "Crazy Train".  You can flag this as not-constructive now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/RDcA7/4/
You have set a max-height and max-width property... removed them, and you have the original image size.
jQuery:

```
$(".pin img").on('click',function(){
    $(this).css({"max-height":"none","max-width":"none"});
});
```

Comment: +1 from me. This fits the spec of the question and does not alter markup at all. No idea why it was downvoted.

Comment: @Daniel pls also help me in removing padding on click..i need the exact source img, pls update the fiddle. thanks...

Comment: @Daniel I have tried this there is a padding at the bottom..i think..that is due to 'diplay:inline-block' in css, pls check that i need the exact source,i dont require box shawdows..blah..blah,I just require the source

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RDcA7/7/  Another option is to kill off the parents styling by using unwrap.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RDcA7/8/ the css call does nothing once you kill the parents.  Edited a little further.

Answer (score 0):

```
imgObject.width = imageObject.naturalWidth;
imgObject.height = imageObject.naturalHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
img.onload=function(){
    console.log("Width",img.naturalWidth);
    console.log("Height",img.naturalHeight);
}

var img = document.getElementByTagName("img")[0];
img.onclick = function(){
this.className = "";
}
```

Comment: where is onclick handling

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code -

Add a class `small` to `<img>` tag -

```
<img class="small" src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2v3VhAp.png" />
```

Adding an onclick listener -

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("small")
})
```

and finally the css -

```
pin img.small {
    width:auto;
    image-rendering:optimizeQuality;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

and here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/moazzam_khan/RDcA7/2/)

if dont want to use jQuery then -

```
var img = document.getElementByTagName("img")[0];
img.onclick = function(){
   this.className = "";
}
```